# Camera Not Opening when Deployed On server Django/Python

Tags: python, django, opencv, face-recognition

Unable to open Camera On server, where its the same copy with Same settings

```
  cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Used this to initialise camera (webcam)
and below code for processing the data stream and below image shows the error on server [click here to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxm4L.png)

```
def identify_faces(video_capture):
    buf_length = 10
    known_conf = 6
    buf = [[]] * buf_length
    i = 0

    process_this_frame = True
    while True:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        rgb_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
        if process_this_frame:
            predictions = predict(rgb_frame, model_path="folder/folder/models/trainedmodel.clf")
        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

        face_names = []

        for name, (top, right, bottom, left) in predictions:
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
            identify1(frame, name, buf, buf_length, known_conf)

            face_names.append(name)

        buf[i] = face_names
        i = (i + 1) % buf_length
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It aims to open the webcam of the *server*, not of the client/browser.

Comment: unable to bypass can you suggest how to process it

Comment: code on server has access only to camera directly connected to server. To user camera has access only user's web brower and JavaScript - and you would have to run web page with `JavaScript` which will use `Canvas` to get image from camera and `AJAX` to send it to server and get back answer.

Comment: I have examples only for `flask`: [furas/python-examples/flask/web camera in browser - canvas - take image and upload to server](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server)